Azure Kubernetes Service with csi secret store error fetching the secrets-store-creds
I have an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster running. And part of setting the environment variables for my pod, i installed the csi-secret-store-provider-azure with helm chart. The first deployment was with default values and everything was working just fine. I was able to access the keyvault and store the secrets in a volume attached to the pod.
After some testing i realized that i cannot reload the volume attached to the pod if i needs to add a new secret or remove one, but i had to delete the volume and deploy it again. Which is not ideal for my case. While reading some documentations i found that the helm chart installed has some values that could help with this. Such as:
csi-secrets-store-provider-azure/csi-secrets-store-provider-azure --set secrets-store-csi-driver.enableSecretRotation=true -n istio-system--set secrets-store-csi-driver.syncSecret.enabled=true

With those values enabled and configured, as of my understanding, i should be able to resync my secrets every 2m.
But unfortunately that was not the case because i started seeing a random warning across my pods. The warning in the events is the following:
Warning  MountRotationFailed  22s (x25 over 4m12s)   csi-secrets-store-rotation  failed to get node publish secret default/secrets-store-creds, err: secrets "default/secrets-store-creds" not found

my yaml deployments for this looks like this:
SecretClassProvider.yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: pod-service-app-config
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: pod-service-app-config
      type: Opaque
      data:
         [.......] my configurations


While in the deployment itself i have the following:
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pod-service
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        nodepool: linuxnode00
      containers:
        - name: pod-service
          image: my-image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: Auth__ClientId
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: pod-service-app-config
                key: KeyToFetch
          volumeMounts:
          - name: pod-service-app-config
            mountPath: "/mnt/pod-service-app-config"
            readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: pod-service-app-config
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "pod-service-app-config"
            nodePublishSecretRef:      
              name: secrets-store-creds

i have the secret secret-store-creds set and is in the same namespace. But i really dont understand what is the root cause issue here if somebody can shade some light on this i would be gratefull.
Please if you need any details, dont hesitate to ask

It looks like you are set up correctly with your Azure Key Vault, AKS, and your Kubernetes secrets. The csi-secrets-store-provider-azure is installed and was working fine initially, but you encountered an issue with the secret rotation feature. The error MountRotationFailed suggests that the CSI driver is having trouble fetching the node publish secret, which is necessary for it to communicate with the Azure Key Vault.
Ensure Role Assignments i.e. ensure you've assigned the necessary roles in Azure Key Vault using RBAC for your service principal (arkokasp) in my case. The service principal needs the Key Vault Secrets User role at minimum to read secrets.

Verify that your SecretProviderClass (pod-service-app-config) has the correct reference to the Azure Key Vault and the correct tenantId. If all good, then you can proceed to ensure that your Kubernetes deployment successfully mounts these secrets into your pod using the CSI Secret Store CSI driver.
First, make sure that your SecretProviderClass is configured correctly. This class should be referencing the Azure Key Vault correctly and must specify the secret you want to access, which is dbusername in this case.
example YAML. Modify this accordingly as per your own environment.
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: my-kv-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: username
      objectName: dbusername
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    keyvaultName: "arkokv"
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: dbusername
          objectType: secret
    tenantId: "id-value"



and apply using
kubectl apply -f secretproviderclass.yaml

Now, deploy a Kubernetes pod that uses this SecretProviderClass.
Example yaml. You can modify it with your own deployment file.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-secrets-demo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-secrets
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-secrets
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "azure-kvname"
          nodePublishSecretRef:
            name: secrets-store-creds

Same way apply it using kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
Confirm the existence of the secret in the Azure Key Vault. Also cross check SecretProviderClass YAML, assuming both dbusername and dbpassword exist in your Key Vault and the permissions are appropriately set.
Example secretprovider yaml.
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: example-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: username  # Key used in your Kubernetes secret to reference dbusername
      objectName: dbusername  # Name of the secret in Azure Key Vault
    - key: password  # Key used in your Kubernetes secret to reference dbpassword
      objectName: dbpassword  # Name of the secret in Azure Key Vault
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"  # Set to "true" if using managed identities, otherwise ensure your service principal is configured correctly
    keyvaultName: "arkokv"  # Name of your Azure Key Vault
    cloudName: "AzurePublicCloud"  # Optional if default
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: dbusername
          objectType: secret  # Object type in Key Vault (could be secret, key, or cert)
          objectVersion: ""  # Leave blank to always fetch the latest version
        - |
          objectName: dbpassword
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
    resourceGroup: "rg-name"  # Resource group where your Key Vault is located
    subscriptionId: "abcd-44fb-efg-hijklmnop"  # Your Azure subscription ID
    tenantId: "id value"  # Your Azure tenant ID

This configuration will allow the CSI driver to fetch the specified secrets from Azure Key Vault and present them as files inside the pods that use this SecretProviderClass.

References:

Troubleshoot Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver


thank you so much for your answer. Just a quick clarification on this. If i want to keep syncing the secrets from the keyvault everytime i add a new one to my SecretClassProvider. Do i need the MountRotation enabled or is enough to have the sync enabled? The question is just to understand if this is necessary for this purpose or not as is giving me constant troubles on this. You configuration is the same i have in my yaml but the error keeps persisting

If you're looking to keep the secrets in your pods up to date with those in Azure Key Vault without having to restart your pods, you will need both secret rotation and secret sync enabled.

thank you once again for your answer. i enabled both but if i add a secret to the SecretProviderClass yaml and update the env configuration and redeploy, i keep getting the error now that the secret (new one) doesnt exist. it stays like this for 2minutes and after again it shows again the error Warning  MountRotationFailed  2s (x20 over 3m2s)     csi-secrets-store-rotation  failed to get node publish secret default/secrets-store-creds, err: secrets "default/secrets-store-creds" not found.  i added my service principle to the keyvault as you suggested

Running into this same issue, since the original deployment succeeds this feels like it may be a bug in the driver... Because it can access the secrets during the initial mount, but then it can't find the same secrets that still exist during the sync.

According to the documentation here
There is a situation where after v.0.1.0 the secrets-store-csi-driver driver has some secrets filtering enabled by default. This is to avoid caching secrets unnecessarily I believe.
To make sure that the secrets are visible, the node published secret needs to be labeled as used using the following command:
kubectl label secret <node publish secret ref name> secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/used=true

And optionally adding the -n <namespace> if needed.
If you do not label the secrets as used you will see errors like the following:

failed to get node publish secret , err: secrets "" not found

